# Cannot receive RemoteExecutionContext messages sent from CRM to Service Bus Queue in Azure Biztalk Service

Tags: azure, dynamics-crm-online, azure-servicebus-queues, biztalk-services

I wasn't able to find a valid schema for the RemoteExecutionContext sent from MS CRM to Azure Service Bus Queue, so I tried a Passthrough Bridge as well as a One-Way Xml Bridge using a dummy schema

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts"
    xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003"
    targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="RemoteExecutionContext">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Processing messages from the queue consistently fails with

> Error = Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
>   happened while submitting message to gateway. 
>   ItemId = 8e9284315e104a759353769633b7c4c2, 
>   RequestId = b442f176-2007-44a6-b818-801bc74f3e2b, 
>   GatewayAddress = default./passthroughbridge1, 
>   PullEndpointName = OutChannelQueue, 
>   PartitionId = 1, 
>   PullRuntimeUrl = 029ba68d-9696-46bf-bd1e-88b8bddff4a8OutChannelQueue; 
>   TraceSource 'Microsoft-Integration-TransportService' event

I registered the Steps sending to Azure directly to the ServiceEndpoint instead of writing a Plugin for posting the Plugin Execution Context.

Peek/Receiving messages from the queue using a simple console application works without problems so I would rule out authentication or connection string issues.

I could not find any example receiving RemoteExecutionContext messages from a queue using Azure Biztalk Services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out I totally missed to limitation that Azure Biztalk Services cannot receive binary messages - even if you try to PassThrough them and try to serialize them in a custom step.

My solution will be to compose a Xml message to send to Azure Service Bus Queue in a custom Plugin without using Service Endpoint registration provided by MS CRM.

---

**Update** 2016 Update 1 will allow to configure the message format and support binary, xml and json formatted messages form the Service Endpoint Registration. See [Walkthrough: Configure Microsoft Azure (SAS) for integration with Dynamics CRM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt697580.aspx) for details. Note the differences in the configuration dialog to previous versions.